Memoization of complete states
Would it be possible to do memoization on complete states of a computer? In other words, would it be possible to map out complete states (of a program or OS) and then memoize them to have a speedup of the system itself by a compiler of the memoized completed states?

Can you elaborate more on what you mean by memoization and why you think that would result in a speed-up of the system? To me caching the entire program state frequently sounds like generally a bad idea given its cost.

Possible, sure, at least in principle (in practice it might be painful to implement).  Good idea, no, probably not.  Speedup, no, I would expect this would lead to a slowdown.  It's very rare that a computer repeats its entire exact state.  For instance, it's common that the state of the computer includes the current date/time somewhere, and that's not going to repeat any time soon.

The memoization process only applies to mapped out functions of programs to then later compile the complete states of the program to the CPU.
